# Aquiline nose vs Roman nose

Tags: phrase-usage

An [aquiline nose](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquiline_nose) (also called a Roman nose or hook nose):

> is a human nose with a prominent bridge, giving it the appearance of being curved or slightly bent. The word aquiline comes from the Latin word aquilinus ("eagle-like"), an allusion to the curved beak of an eagle.

(Wikipedia)

Why is an aquiline nose also called "Roman" nose?

Do the two definitions refer to the same kind of nose or are there differences between them?

Comment: Because Italians have big noses, and describing someone's nose as *big* has insulting connotations, but describing it as *Roman*, conjuring aristocratic images of marble and Caeser and of of the most venerated empires in the history of mankind softens the blow a bit. And don't shoot me - I'm half Italian. And the other half Jewish. So you can picture *my* nose.

Comment: @DanBron - I see, but the same could be true also for Ancient Greece  marble statues.

Comment: Do Greeks have big noses? That's a serious question, I don't know.

Comment: @DanBron  - I am not sure it is about "big" noses, but hooked ones, if I understand the meaning correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that is closer to the truth, I imagine

Comment: [And now I know how Joan of Arc felt / Now I know how Joan of Arc felt / As flames rose to aquiline nose / And her Walkman started to melt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkrVNaf7UWk) - it just doesn't scan as well that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Roman nose*** and ***aquiline nose*** are synonymous.

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/roman-nose?q=roman+nose) defines ***Roman nose*** as:

> a nose with a high bridge.

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/aquiline) defines ***aquiline*** as:

> (Of a person's nose) hooked or curved like an eagle's beak.

A nose with a high bridge *is* hooked or curved like an eagle's beak. So absent particular connotations elicited by "Rome" and "eagle", the terms are synonymous.

---

As to the question of *why* an aquiline nose is also called a Roman nose, it is (presumably) because that particular facial morphology is associated (not necessarily justly) with people from Italy, or, more broadly, the Mediterranean region once controlled by the Roman Empire. The [page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquiline_nose) you link in your question even declares that the nose is "often seen in the Mediterranean race".

---

Regarding earliest uses, [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=Roman+nose) says "*Roman nose* is from 1620s" and [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/roman-nose) traces its origin to between 1615-1625.

Here are some of the earliest occurrences (I could find) of the term used with its morphological sense:

> A surly Nonconformist Teacher,
>   By solemn Face, some Alley Preacher,
>   With Lanthorn Jaws and **Roman Nose**,
>   A flapping Hat without a Rose
>
> ([E. Ward, *The Wandring Spy*, 1729](https://books.google.com/books?id=EGETAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA32&dq=%22roman%20nose%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZp7i4o7rNAhXHTCYKHerNB6sQ6AEINjAF#v=onepage&q=%22roman%20nose%22&f=false))

> [...] and from thence this examinate and sir Thomas Harris went to his house at Boreacton that night, where he found one mr. Kynaston, a tall man, with a lean face, and a **Roman nose**; but did not see him afterwards.
>
> ([*A Collection of the State Papers of John Thurloe*, 1742](https://books.google.com/books?id=6OFXAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA286&dq=%22roman+nose%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPzJP4m7rNAhWBbSYKHZ9hCckQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22roman%20nose%22&f=false))

It is unlikely that either of these is a first occurrence, but these passages demonstrate that the expression was used at least as early as 1729.

In a translation of Rabelais, *aquiline nose* is used as early as 1738:

> Panurge was of a middle stature, not too high nor too low, and had somewhat an **aquiline nose**, made like the handle of a razor.
>
> ([Translated by J. Ozell, *The works of Francis Rabelais*, 1738](https://books.google.com/books?id=el5UAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA116&dq=%22aquiline%20nose%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjaoeDBoLrNAhVK5yYKHbU6BtgQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22aquiline%20nose%22&f=false))

Rabelais' original phrase was *le nez un peu aquilin* ("a slightly aquiline nose"—[page 173, here](https://archive.org/details/gargantuaetpanta01rabe)). This was originally written ca. 1532, which lends plausibility to the idea that *aquiline nose* could have been in English circulation as early as then.

Answer (score 3):

The word *eagle*  is *aquila* in Italian, and it is well-known that an eagle's "nose" is curved;  a *hooked nose* in English is often called a *beak* or [*beaked nose*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/beaked).

> Adj.1. **beaked** - having or resembling a beak.

The first picture on the left, depicts an eagle's head whose beak is compared to that of the  gentleman's nose. The [description](http://www.summagallicana.it/Volume3/C.VIIII.a.htm) (translated) says:

> **Naso adunco** o **aquilino**: *magnanimi e animo regale*
>   **Hooked nose** or **aquiline**; magnanimous and noble person (regal/royal= noble)

[image]

If we consider that one of the most iconic Roman emperors, [Tiberius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiberius), had an aquiline nose himself, it's easy to see why *aquiline* (“aquilino”) and (“Romano”) became  associated with one and the other.

[image]

**Of possible interest**

The **eagle** has long been associated with the Roman Empire, it represented the city's political and sovereign power. The soldier who had the honour of carrying the legion's [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colours,_standards_and_guidons) was called an  ***aquilifer***. The protection of the eagle, the Empire's emblem, was paramount and soldiers were expected to protect it even at the cost of their own lives.

Comment: In the "infographic" above, the face paired with the dog is actually a Roman nose. A Roman nose is perfectly straight and there is little to no dip from the brow to the bridge. Like most Greek (actually) astatues that the Romans made so many copies/exact replicas of (more than "copied" as in copped).

Answer (score 0):

I always thought of and heard "aquiline nose" as a term of flattery a fine curved nose whereas a "Roman nose" was used to describe a large curved nose.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage.  This answer will be taken more seriously if you have citations for the information.